# Rails devise login not working after Heroku upgrade to heroku-20 stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I just upgraded my Heroku stack from heroku-16 to heroku-20.
Now, my users cannot login.  This is the error message in the logs:
`Completed 401 Unauthorized in 83ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)`

I rollbacked to heroku-16 stack and confirmed the problem is not there (users can login successfully).

If it helps, in my Gemfile I use:

gem 'devise', '4.6.1'

gem 'rails', '5.2.2'

ruby  '2.6.6'

I do not know how to debug as login/logout works fine in my development area.  Any ideas what could the issue be?

Comment: As a start, you should try to set a staging app at Heroku, migrate to the 20 stack and get the server logs when you attempt to login a Devise account

Comment: That error message is not sufficient. Is there additional relevant log output?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The error was in my Gemfile where I had both a devise gem and a bcrypt-ruby gem.   Commenting out the bcrypt-ruby gem solved the problem (devise comes with bcrypt so presumably there was some sort of clash).
I do not know why using heroku-20 vs. heroku-16 stacks operated differently but it was a red herring.

FYI, I came across the clue when I tried to debug by doing something other than logging in: creating a new user account.  This action failed but the error log referred to bcrypt-ruby which set me on the path to solving my problem.